# Rails 5. Association one to one, updating record create new one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, one-to-one

Model User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address, foreign_key: :user_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

Model Address

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

Controller User, everything happen here

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def home # method which I use to display form
     @user = User.find_by :id => session[:id]
   end

   def update # method for updating data
     @user = User.find(session[:id])
     if @user.update(user_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Update successfully"
       redirect_to home_path
     else
       flash[:error] = "Can not update"
       redirect_to home_path
     end
   end

   private
     def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, images_attributes: [:image_link, :image_description], address_attributes: [:city, :street, :home_number, :post_code, :country])
     end
end
```

Updating form:

```
<%= form_for @user, :html => { :id => "update-form", :class => "update-form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
  <%= f.fields_for :address do |a| %>
    <%= a.text_field :city %>
    <%= a.text_field :street %>
    <%= a.number_field :home_number %>
    <%= a.text_field :post_code %>
    <%= a.text_field :country %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When I submitting my form, it shows me everything is fine, I mean "Update successfully", but in database its looks like new record is added to address table, but user table is updated properly. Can someone give me explanation why? I am looking answers in google but nothing helps me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I submitting my form, it shows me everything is fine, I mean
>   "Update successfully", but in database its looks like new record is
>   added to address table, but user table is updated properly. Can
>   someone give me explanation why?

This is due to the nature of `strong params`. It expects `:id` **to be permitted** for the `nested_attributes` to update properly, else a new record is created instead. Permit the `:id` and you are good to go.

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, images_attributes: [:id, :image_link, :image_description], address_attributes: [:id, :city, :street, :home_number, :post_code, :country])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code in your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def home # method which I use to display form
     @user = User.find_by :id => session[:id]
   end

   def update # method for updating data
     @user = User.find(session[:id])
     if @user.update(user_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Update successfully"
       redirect_to home_path
     else
       flash[:error] = "Can not update"
       redirect_to home_path
     end
   end

   private
     def user_params
       params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, images_attributes: [:image_link, :image_description], address_attributes: [:id, :city, :street, :home_number, :post_code, :country])
     end
end
```